# Repeating animation restarting button's positions

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I am new to coding in Swift. I am working with animations, and I have a problem.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(waitTime), delay: 0, options: [.allowUserInteraction, .allowAnimatedContent, .curveLinear, .repeat], animations: {

    UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount(Float(self.clickAccuracy))

    // Animate tiles going down
    self.tileButton1.center.y += self.tileButtonExample.frame.height / CGFloat(self.clickAccuracy)
    self.tileButton2.center.y += self.tileButtonExample.frame.height / CGFloat(self.clickAccuracy)
    self.tileButton3.center.y += self.tileButtonExample.frame.height / CGFloat(self.clickAccuracy)
    self.tileButton4.center.y += self.tileButtonExample.frame.height / CGFloat(self.clickAccuracy)
    self.tileButton5.center.y += self.tileButtonExample.frame.height / CGFloat(self.clickAccuracy)

})
```

Here, I want to repeat an animation of a UIButton moving down. (I have to repeat the animation in smaller blocks because I want to be able to click on the moving button). However, the buttons are going down as far as they are meant to, but instead of repeating again from that position, it resets. This causes an infinite flicker.

All I need is for the buttons to move down, without the position restarting to its original position, so I can have a smooth animation. Thanks!

**Here is a video**
https://i.imgflip.com/27uzl3.gif

Comment: @rmaddy I do not want the animation to reverse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the original way I did didn't seem to work. So I changed it to this:

```
var numberOfIterations = 0

func repeatAnimation() {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(waitTime), delay: 0, options: [.allowUserInteraction, .allowAnimatedContent, .curveLinear, .curveLinear], animations: {

        //UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount(Float(self.clickAccuracy))

        // Animate tiles going down
        self.tileButton1.center.y += self.tileButtonExample.frame.height / CGFloat(self.clickAccuracy)
        self.tileButton2.center.y += self.tileButtonExample.frame.height / CGFloat(self.clickAccuracy)
        self.tileButton3.center.y += self.tileButtonExample.frame.height / CGFloat(self.clickAccuracy)
        self.tileButton4.center.y += self.tileButtonExample.frame.height / CGFloat(self.clickAccuracy)
        self.tileButton5.center.y += self.tileButtonExample.frame.height / CGFloat(self.clickAccuracy)

    }, completion: { (Finished) in

        numberOfIterations += 1

        // Repeat
        if numberOfIterations != self.clickAccuracy {

            self.repeatAnimation()

        }

    })

}
```

When @rmaddy gave me this answer, we forgot to remove the `setAnimationRepeatCount` (commented out). To make this repeat a set number of times, I put an `if` statement in the completion block.

I also got rid of `.repeat` in the animation options.

Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: happy to see again renamed to repeatAnimation